# comparing reg keys with old backup CMD line

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm trying to compare an old backup of the registry with the current version and I want to see the difference. 
REG COMPARE takes in the two keys and even can span two machines but I don't know how to get it to look at a backup file rather than another machine. I need this to be a CMD line solution without installing anything new. Ultimately, I can write a batch file that will read and parse the backup and compare it with each of the values but this seems extravagant when it can already look at two different machines I should be able to point it to a file.

Comment: Well the help file for `REG COMPARE` shows no syntax for comparing registry backup files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an admin, you can load the registry backup into a temporary key...

```
REG LOAD HKU\TEMP c:\backup\ntuser.dat
```

...then compare your desired subtree...

```
REG COMPARE HKU\[KEY-OF-INTEREST] HKU\TEMP\[KEY-OF-INTEREST]
```

...and finally unload the backup from the registry:

```
REG UNLOAD HKU\TEMP
```